# Visual Studio 2015 Method Info

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, codelens

I was using Visual Studio 2015 RC for a while and one of the handy features was a line of text above each method/class definition that had info about the method or class (number of references, date of last edit, name of last editor).

[image: Method Definition]

But I just installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and this information is gone. Does anybody know how to re-enable this feature?

Comment: In the VS IDE, try Ctrl-Q, to get to the search box in the top right. In that box type "codelens" and see if anything comes up. Maybe it is possible to turn it on/off by a setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a feature of Visual Studio called [CodeLens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx).

You can enable it by going to **Tools** | **Options** | **Text Editor** | **All** | **Languages** | **Code Information Indicators**.

You could also use the [Quick Launch feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnstudents/archive/2013/12/16/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-quick-launch-where-was-that-option-menu-item.aspx)  (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) to search for "CodeLens".

Comment: In VS2015 this feature is not available in the Community version. Took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: For VS2015 Enterprise, this is available in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All  Languages -> CodeLens.